# Given an alternative algebra A, is the algebra generated by two commutative, associative subalgebras B and C always associative?

Tags: nonassociative-algebras

The algebras are over a field.

The answer to the question is yes when B and C are generated by 1 element each. Over the octonions, the answer to the question is then yes. What about in general?